# Loading big file in c

Tags: c, windows

This is my program code that can load inputs 1GB, 2GB, but I would need to load files larger than 2GB. I work at Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *stream;
    size_t size;
    int fileSize = 0;
    char *input;

    // Open file, find the size of it
    stream = fopen("3GB.bin", "rb");
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(stream);
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    input = (char *)malloc(fileSize + 1);

    // Stream file into memory
    size = fread(input, 1, fileSize, stream);
    input[size] = 0;
    fclose(stream);

    printf("size file is: %d\n", fileSize);

    free(input);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it does not load files larger than 2GB at all...
Don't know where the problem is?

Comment: `int fileSize` -- you may want to look at the limits of the int type.

Comment: I exchanged for data type uint32_t which should cover 3GB, 4GB but the result is the same

Comment: What is the result actually? Which part failed and in what way? You probably need to add a bit of error handling for that.

Comment: The same limit might also apply for called functions or their underlying Windows API calls. You will need to check this, for example by intensely reading their documentation. 2GB is a kind of magic limit.

Comment: You probably want this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64

Comment: Changing the data type you use does not help, because `ftell` returns a 32 bit signed integer anyway (on Windows `long` is 32 bits, same as `int`).

Comment: You probaly should think about doing something more efficient than copying the entire file into memory. Most operating systems (including Windows) provide an api to map files into memory without copying them. You have to use a platform dependent api though, so you must decide for yourself if that is something that you can live with.

Comment: @hyde Yes, you were right, I changed the fseek function to _fseeki64 and the _ftelli64 function and the program already loaded my 4 GB file.

Comment: Are you targeting x86 or x64? With x86 the maximum memory you can address is 4GB minus what is already used by the system. And you might also not be able to allocate such large quantities of memory in one piece because of memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    size_t size;
    uint32_t fileSize = 0;
    char *input;
    int result1, result2;

    // Open file, find the size of it
    stream = fopen("4GB.bin", "rb");
    if (result1 = _fseeki64(stream, 0L, SEEK_END) != 0)
    {
        printf("_fseeki64 result1 error\n");
    }
    fileSize = _ftelli64(stream);

    if (result2 = _fseeki64(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET)!= 0)
    {
        printf("_fseeki64 result2 error\n");
    }

    input = (char *) malloc(fileSize + 1);

    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }


    //Stream file into memory
    size = fread(input, 1, fileSize, stream);
    input[size] = 0;
    fclose(stream);

    printf("size file is: %u\n", fileSize);

    free(input);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What's the `input[size] = 0;` for? The filename "3GB.bin" suggests that this is binary data.